# how do i wrtite django fbv to class based view

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have two user types a and b i need to write the below fbv into class based Logoutview(auth.view) how do i write the below fbv to cbv

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def logout(request):

    if request.user.usertype_a:
        logout(request)
        return redirect(reverse('user_a_login'))
    else:
        logout(request)
        return redirect(reverse('user_b_login'))
```

Comment: did any of these answers work for you?

Comment: that i already wrote before your post bro i wanted that to be specific with LogoutView

Comment: @Sumithran Sorry bro i thought it was not needed

Comment: No need to be sorry but you have to responsible when people are investing their time on your problem.

Comment: @Sumithran I agree bro i was in some hurry and forgot

Comment: @Sumithran By the way bro plz take a glance at my newly posted question if ur free that would be appreciable

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
from django.views import View

class LogOutView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
    
        if request.user.usertype_a:
            return redirect(reverse('user_a_login'))
    
        return redirect(reverse('user_b_login'))
```

Or you can Use [LogoutView](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) and override its dispatch method for custom redirections

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```